# How does Spark achieve sort order?

Tags: sorting, apache-spark

Assume I have a list of Strings. I filter & sort them, and collect the result to driver. However, things are distributed, and each RDD has it's own part of original list. So, how does Spark achieve the final sorted order, does it merge results?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sorting in Spark is a multiphase process which requires shuffling:

1. input RDD is sampled and this sample is used to compute boundaries for each output partition (`sample` followed by `collect`)
2. input RDD is partitioned using `rangePartitioner` with boundaries computed in the first step (`partitionBy`)
3. each partition from the second step is sorted locally (`mapPartitions`)

When the data is collected, all that is left is to follow the order defined by the partitioner.

Above steps are clearly reflected in a debug string:

```scala
scala> val rdd = sc.parallelize(Seq(4, 2, 5, 3, 1))
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Int] = ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at ...

scala> rdd.sortBy(identity).toDebugString
res1: String = 
(6) MapPartitionsRDD[10] at sortBy at <console>:24 [] // Sort partitions
 |  ShuffledRDD[9] at sortBy at <console>:24 [] // Shuffle
 +-(8) MapPartitionsRDD[6] at sortBy at <console>:24 [] // Pre-shuffle steps
    |  ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at <console>:21 [] // Parallelize
```

Comment: Great answer. If I understand correctly, before collecting, Spark shuffle data into "sorted" partition that are separated by boundaries which are quantiles from a data sample ? For example, with 50 partitions, there will be a 1st partition for all item below the "sampled 2% quantile item", a 2nd partition from the 2% quantile to the 4% one, etc... ?

Comment: One other question: how do you find this information? Looking into the spark code, I find the logical plan node, such as `Sort(...) extends UnitaryNode`, which are the plan definition, but not the sorting algorithm.